# Longest common prefix and suffix of 2 arrays

Tags: discrete-mathematics, contest-math

I'm solving a programming problem, where I'm given 2 arrays, and I want to find the longest common prefix and suffix. This is straightforward when there's no overlap, but what happens in the case of overlap? By "overlap" I mean part of the common prefix is also part of the common suffix.

First, I want to figure out when it's possible for there to be overlap. I think this is more easily thought of in 2 cases, when the 2 arrays are equal size and when they're not.

1. When the arrays are equal size. In this case, I believe the 2 arrays have to be identical, otherwise there will be no overlap.
2. When the arrays are different size. This case seems trickier, though in my mind it seems  for their to be overlap, either the first array must be exactly equal to the first part of the second array or vice versa. Is this a necessary and sufficient condition? e.g., $[1]$ and $[1,1]$.

Comment: $[1, 2, 3]$ and $[1, 2, 3, 4]$ have no common suffix, so I don't understand your example in case 2. It's not 100% clear what you mean by overlap: do the longest common prefix and longest common suffix of $[1, 2, 3]$ and $[1, 2, 3, 3]$ overlap? And why do you care? The natural algorithms for finding these things aren't affected by overlap.

Comment: @RobArthan The programming question mentions that if there's overlap, I should return the prefix as normal, and for the suffix, I should remove the part that overlaps with the prefix, so I'm a bit confused how this works in the second case. In the first case is it's straightforward, but maybe my premise is wrong in the second case, i.e., if the 2 strings are unequal in size, then it's not possible for prefix&suffix to overlap?

Comment: @RobArthan ahh, for the second case, let me change it to another example

Comment: I think I get the idea. I think you just need to find the common prefix first. The index of the last element of the longest common prefix will be the same in both arrays, say $I$, then when you are working from the ends of the arrays to find the longest common suffix, stop when the index into either array reaches $I$. I think it's a bit tricky to say exactly when overlap occurs, but you don't need to do that.

Comment: @RobArthan ahh yeah that's a good point, thanks. I was also curious from a mathematical standpoint on how to prove the conditions that are sufficient for overlap